# JavaScript for picking an ID from table

Tags: javascript

I need to get value of the first cell from table (ID's cell). Here's part of code: I need some sort of script that just returns the value of  with echo $results['ID'] after clicking on a table row.

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Imie</th><th>Nazwisko</th><th>PESEL</th><th>Data Urodzenia</th><th>Miejscowość</th><th>Adres</th><th>Kod Pocztowy</th><th>Województwo</th><th>Telefon</th><th>E-Mail</th><th>Notatki</th><th>Zdjęcie</th><th>Historia</th><th>Umów</th><th>Edytuj</th><th>Usuń</th></tr>   ";          
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
  echo "<tr><td>";          
  echo $results['ID'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['imie'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['nazwisko'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['pesel'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['data'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['miejscowosc'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['adres'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['kodpocztowy'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['wojewodztwo'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['telefon'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['email'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['notatki'];
}
```

Comment: Add complete HTML, instead of PHP, also add your attempts to solve the problem

Comment: I have had no attempts at all. I dont have any idea how to create such a script.

Comment: `View Source` in browser will give you the resulting HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with jQuery, you assign a click handler to all table-rows, then you find the contents of the first element of that row.

```
$("tr").click(function() { //assign click handler to rows
     var id = $(this).children().first().html() //get content of first element of row
    console.log(id) //write the id to the browsers console
})
```

Full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3n4czph/

If you are not familiar with jQuery, you need to include it with a script tag, then run the code above on your page when it loads

Comment: http://screenshooter.net/102666042/beydeny I did that thing, and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: if you look at the full jsFiddle example you can see that you need some more code, it needs to be run in the document ready handler: $(function() {HERE})